# Email Domain Too Long

Tags: email, apex-email-service

Hi Just wanna how to make the email shorter in email services please help for this thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The email address is defined by Salesforce and you cannot modify it.

Maybe you have a bit of an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Is it too long to use that Email Address in salesforce what if a customer will email to email services ????????????????? thank you help me please

Comment: This is why you got downvoted. You did not ask a complete question. Your question as posted was answered

Comment: Sorry about that I am new with this. My question is instead of using a long Email Address I want to make it short to be use by customer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shorter alias in a variety of ways, including Google Groups. See the **`Add members to your Group`** section of [this groups help document](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465464?hl=en):

> **Add members to your Group**
>
> You can directly add up to 10 people to your Group at once. Only 25 people can be directly added to a Group.
>
> 1. Sign in to Google Groups.
> 2. Click My Groups.
> 3. Choose a group.
> 4. Near the top right, click Manage.
> 5. On the left, click Members and then Direct add members.
> 6. Enter the email addresses of the people to add.
> 7. Enter a welcome message.
> 8. Set how members will get email from the group.
> 9. Click Add.

So copy that long email address and add it to the group as a member. Now every time someone sends an email to `yourShortAlias@gmail.com` it will forward the message on to your email service.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson what if the other email domains what will happen ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AndriaLarson sorry about that your answer is on gmail.com what if the other email domains like yahoo.com or facebook.com

Comment: Is that possible? or I need to create another group again

Comment: Surely you get the idea and can investigate that for yourself...